# Need help in animation Opengl c/c++

Tags: c++, c, opengl, animation

I was trying to bounce it up when a point reaches to the bottom. Unfortunately, it just keeps going down. Here is the code:

```
void Timer(int value) {
    if (value) {
        if(initMpoints[1][1] <= 500 && initMpoints[0][1] >= 0) {
            txForC -= 0;
            tyForC -= 5;            //Move C downward.
            txForM -= 0;
            tyForM -= 5;
            if (initMpoints[0][1] == 0) {
                txForC += 0;
                tyForC += 5;            //Move C downward.
                txForM += 0;
                tyForM += 5;
            }
        }

    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, value);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The code here is not completely done. Please tell me if I did something from the start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Can you post a more meaningful code snippet? Why are you undoing the changes to `txForC` etc. when `initMpoints[0][1] == 0`, instead of simply ruling out this condition from the first `if()` statement? What do these variables represent? And how does your code know when a point has reached the bottom? Have you checked what will happen if the point overshoots the bottom position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good and more natural example of bounce amination could be done by usage `abs(sin(x))` function.

[image]

in your case I shall rewrite your function like this.

```
// Speed of bouncing
float fSpeed = 0.01f;
float fPI = 3.1415926f;

// Height of bouncing
float fHeight = 100.0f;

void Timer(int iValue)
{
    static float fAngle = 0.0;

    // if animation enabled
    if (iValue)
    {
        tyForC = fHeight * abs(sin(fAngle));
        tyForM = fHeight * abs(sin(fAngle));

        // Go to next position
        fAngle += fSpeed;
    }

    // Restore previous value to avoid bitgrid overflow
    if (fAngle >= (4.0f * fPI - fSpeed / 2.0))
    {
        fAngle = 0.0f;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, iValue);
}
```

for teeth like animation in your case the code will be like

```
float fHeight = 100.0f;

void Timer(int iValue)
{
    static float deltaC = 5.0f;
    static float deltaM = 5.0f;

    if (iValue)
    {
        tyForC += deltaC;
        tyForM += deltaM;

        if (tyForC <= 0 || tyForC >= fHeight)
            deltaC *= -1.0f;

        if (tyForM <= 0 || tyForM >= fHeight)
            deltaM *= -1.0f;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, iValue);
}
```

Comment: @MC Mad Moefat: Did I answer your question?

Comment: thank you it really helped... I'm sorry if my programming is bad. Still studying though. Thanks.